# Using pop up windows in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is a part of the script that I am using and it is working correctly.

```
try:
    (sshin1, sshout1, ssherr1) = proxy_client.exec_command(mycommand)
    print sshout1.read()
    mytext=sshout1.read()
    print type(mytext)
except:
    print "error while executing the command on remote host"
```

But when I add this line, at the end, it creates a pop-up window with "Say Hello" title but does not show the mytext contents.

```
tkMessageBox.showinfo("Say Hello", mytext)
```

The print statement in the try block will display the output to the terminal. How do I show the same output in a pop-up window?

update:

The text shown in the pop-up window can not be copied and pasted to some other application like notepad. Is there any easy way?

Answer (score 0):

I just had to comment out the print statement. For some reason the .read() output was getting destroyed after printing.

```
#print sshout1.read()
```

Comment: when you do `print sshout1.read()`, it is reading all of the data. It isn't destroying it, it's simply reading it all. Imagine that you have a pitcher of water, and each time you call `.read()` you pour out the contents of the pitcher. So, you pour it all out with the print statement, and then the next statement tries to pour it out but the pitcher is empty.